# Error Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/abc.txt" is denied in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to run a Xamarin Android app on Android 8 API Level 26 emulator. Its giving exception when I am trying to write logs to file.

**Exception:**

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "/storage/emulated/0/abc.txt" is denied

**Code:**

```
string filename = "abc.txt";
var documentsPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, filename);
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

I have given the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions also.

**Target Android Version:** Android 8.0 API Level 26 Oreo

**Exception Details:**

> {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   "/storage/emulated/0/NECMobilePos_log21092018.txt" is denied. at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
>   System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001aa] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-6/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:239
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean isAsync, System.Boolean
>   anonymous) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-6/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:149
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android-d15-6/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:86
>   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess)
>   at NECMobilePOS.Client.DroidLatest.FileLogger_Android.SaveText
>   (System.String filenamePassed, System.String text) [0x000d1] in
>   C:\ABC\XYZ\FileLogger_Android.cs:73 }

Comment: Sounds like you haven't explicitly asked the user for permission and here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911486/xamarin-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied/46933816#46933816)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Versions >= 23, you need to provide the Runtime Permissions. You can go through the document from the link below.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Or for testing now, you can go to app permissions and allow storage permission.

Comment: Awesome, Thank you sharmaji