# How can I download (from URL) an apk with a button in xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, webclient

I used `WebClient` to download a file in my apk. But I got this error:
Unhandled Exception:

System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

And this is the code that I tried:

```
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                
                    client.DownloadFile(
                        "https://code.org/images/social-media/code-2018-creativity.png",
                        @"j:\storage\emulated\legacy\Download\code-2018-creativity.png");
                
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide us more details about the exception? (maybe the InnerException will help)

Comment: I got this from console: 06-09 18:29:56.662 I/mono-stdout( 3959): An exception occurred during a WebClient request. Access to the path "/j:\storage\emulated\legacy\Download\code-2018-creativity.png" is denied.

Comment: Do you have any idea @CiubotariuFlorin ?

Comment: What Android version are you using?

Comment: my minSdkVersion is set on API 16 @CiubotariuFlorin.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only referring to a WebException, it may have to do with one of these cases:

- The URI formed by combining `BaseAddress` and `address` is invalid.
- The file or destination folder does not exist. Make sure your path to
  the destination folder already exists and that you have permissions to access it.
- An error occurred while
  downloading data.

If you provide us more information about the exception we may be able to reduce the error to one of these cases. To get the `InnerException` you can do something like this:

```
{
  using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
  {
    try
    {
      client.DownloadFile (
        "https://code.org/images/social-media/code-2018-creativity.png",
        @"j:\storage\emulated\legacy\Download\code-2018-creativity.png");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      while (ex != null)
      {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this from console:
06-09 18:29:56.662 I/mono-stdout( 3959): An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
Access to the path "/j:\storage\emulated\legacy\Download\code-2018-creativity.png" is denied.

what should i do now?

Comment: I changed the path to: @"j:\sdcard\code-2018-creativity.png"
and added these permissions  to manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

but it didn't help.

Comment: Have you got any idea @DiogoRocha?

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask permissions on run time even you have mentioned them in your manifest file if you are running Android api level 23 or greater.

Have a look at this blog would help about how to ask a run time permission:[requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/)

Also, this is the official sample of how to check [RuntimePermissions](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/android-m/RuntimePermissions)

Refer: [xamarin-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911486/xamarin-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-denied)

**Update:**

To ask run time permissions, you can use this plugin:[Plugin.Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions/), install it to your project.

And then, call `CheckMyPermissionAsync();` before you download the file:

```
private void FabOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    View view = (View) sender;

    CheckMyPermissionAsync();
}
```

In the method `CheckMyPermissionAsync()`, check your Storage permission and then download file:

```
 public async void CheckMyPermissionAsync()
        {

            var permissionsStartList = new List<Permission>()
            {
                Permission.Storage
            };

            var permissionsNeededList = new List<Permission>();
            try
            {
                foreach (var permission in permissionsStartList)
                {
                    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(permission);
                    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    {
                        permissionsNeededList.Add(permission);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(permissionsNeededList.ToArray());

            //Check the persimmison again
            var storeagePermission = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);

            if (storeagePermission == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                //Download file here
                DownloadFile("http://www.dada-data.net/uploads/image/hausmann_abcd.jpg", "XF_Downloads");
            }
            else {

                Console.WriteLine("No permissions");
            }         
        }
```

You can check the result in the completed event:

```
private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("success");
    }
    else
    {
        if (OnFileDownloaded != null) { }
        Console.WriteLine("fail");
    }
}
```

Note: pay attention to your filePath,make sure your path is correct, I use:

```
string pathToNewFolder = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, folder);
```

I updated my sample here: [runtime-permission-xamarin.android](https://github.com/XfHua/runtime-permission-xamarin.android)

Comment: I read  links you refrenced but excuse me @JackHua, i didn't realy understand what should i do now.

Comment: @mohamadaminkaviyani I will share a sample to you to tell you what you should do. I will update it later.

Comment: thank you so much @JackHua.
I just tested the app on my phone (the past results were taken from emulator)  and it didn't launch even :|

Comment: @mohamadaminkaviyani See my edited answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank u so much @JackHua. The problem is solved, but i had an embarrassing mistake:
@"j:\storage\emulated\legacy\Download\code-2018-creativity.png"
The correct form is:
@"j:/storage/emulated/legacy/Download/code-2018-creativity.png"

Comment: @mohamadaminkaviyani Can you please accept this answer if it is helpful to you? We can help more people with same problem!